# Does *metafor* package in R provide forest plot for robust random effects models

Tags: r, metafor

I have fit a *robust random-effects* meta-regression model using `metafor` package in `R`.

My full [**data**](https://github.com/izeh/m/blob/master/d.csv), as well as reproducible `R` code appear below.

**Questions:**

**(1)** What are the meaning and interpretation of grey-colored diamonds appearing over CIs?

**(2)** I won't get an overall mean effect when I have moderators, correct?

```
library(metafor)
d <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/izeh/m/master/d.csv", h = T) ## DATA

res <- robust(rma.uni(yi = dint, sei = SD, mods = ~es.type, data = d, slab = d$study.name), 
              cluster = d$id)

forest(res)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Quoting from `help(forest.rma)`: "For models involving moderators, the fitted value for each study is added as a polygon to the plot." So, the grey-colored diamonds (or polygons) are the fitted values and the width of the diamonds/polygons reflects the width of the CI for the fitted values.

**2)** No, since there is no longer a single overall effect when your model includes moderators.

Comment: Wolfgang, [**robumeta**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/robumeta/robumeta.pdf) by Tipton et al (who promoted *Robust Variance Estimation [RVE] for meta-analysis*) does two different types of robust meta-regression **"Hierarchical"** and **"Correlated"**. The weighting for two is different, I was wondering which of these two approaches is used in `metafor`? Given RVE purpose is partly to prevent meta-analysts from aggregating effect sizes from a single study, I guess, it would be helpful if the forestplot for RVE models label *studies*, and *effect sizes within studies* separately.

Comment: Neither. In metafor, you specify the random effects structure as deemed necessary for your data (plus the var-cov matrix of the sampling errors via ``V``), which then determines the weights or weight matrix (if the model implied marginal var-cov matrix is not diagonal).

Comment: @Wolfgang, I think rnorouzian is talking about **`rma.uni()`** but your answer is about **`rma.mv()`**! In [**robumeta**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/robumeta/robumeta.pdf), **"Correlated Structure"** is not a multi-level model. I appreciate if you clarify your answer to rnorouzian based on [**This Paper by Tipton**](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.02220.pdf)?

Comment: If you have multilevel/multivariate data, then you should fit an appropriate model using `rma.mv()`. If there are parts of that model that are not fully specified (e.g., due to unknown correlations among multiple outcomes), then one should fit a model that approximates the fully specified model and then use cluster-robust methods to obtain appropriate inferences about the fixed effects.

Comment: @Wolfgang, there obviously is a difference of opinion between you and Tipton on addressing the unknown correlations among multiple outcomes. While Tipton proposes weights based on a working model of the unknown covariance  *(i.e., hierarchical and correlated effects)*, you seem to advocate a different approach. Thanks, for the clarification.

Comment: I don't think there are differences in opinion. I also suggest to use a working model (which then implies a certain set of weights or a weight matrix) before using cluster robust inference methods. There are some differences in the details, but the general approach is the same.